# Clickhouse client doesn't display data properly on linux screen

Tags: linux, clickhouse

I have recently installed clickhouse with version 20.11.4.13, It is working fine on base screen, but when I connect to new screen using `screen -S clickhouse-query` command. and run `'show tables'` using clickhouse client, The output is not displayed properly(Please check the attached screenshot of output)
[image: output of query 'show tables']

can anyone please help me here, what is the issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
man screen
-U Run screen in UTF-8 mode.
```

Clickhouse client only utf8

screen -US clickhouse-query